# Download file with ajax in C# .net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, model-view-controller

I have tried to use the following code to download file with ajax in C# .net MVC. For some reason, there is not working. Does anyone know why?

I'm expecting the file will be download or a window dialog will be pop up to ask for the user to select the save directory once function downloadFile have been call

Javascript:

```
function downloadFile(even) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Download",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            fileName: even.id
        },
        success: function (returnValue) {
            window.location = returnValue;
        },
        error: function (data) {

        }
    });
}
```

C# script:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public virtual FileResult Download(string fileName)
{
    var file = (fileName.Contains("hl7s") == true ? fileName + ".zip" : fileName + ".txt");
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\temp\"+ file);
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

Comment: You cannot use AJAX to download file with `FileResult`. Use `[HttpGet]` and `ActionLink` helper pointing to desired action if you want to download it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that straight forward to do this, however, there is a script that can help you. I normally use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to do this, it is open source. FileSaver helps solve browser incompatibilities, it is well tested too.

Here is a code snippet I lift from my current project. This is plain javascript and does not require jQuery or anything.

In this sample, the filename is hardcoded to 'my_excel_file.xlsx', but you can get the filename from the api if you expose a proper header from the api. I think I answered how to handle that somewhere in SO.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="FileSaver.min.js"></script>
  <script>        
    function download() {            
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "http://your.url", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
        //xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ......");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: "octet/stream"});
                var fileName = "my_excel_file.xlsx";
                saveAs(blob, fileName);
            }
        }
        xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        xhr.send();
    }        
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="javascript:download()">Download Excel File</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use HTML download attribute to download file

```
<a href="you file location" download></a>
```

Please refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) link for more information